# Flutter Safe Area and Scaffold with AppBar being overlapped by StatusBar and Camera bump

Tags: flutter

I recently implemented null-safety across my project and changed lots of code at the same time. After the change I can't seem to get the Safe area to have any effect and it was working previously (avoiding the camera bump and status bar at the top). I can't figure out what I could be doing wrong and am unable to get it to work even on an extremely basic screen.
I'm also unable to get the Appbar with scaffold to avoid the status bar and camera, which I believe it typically does.

The issue happens on all screens of my app, and happens on both the simulator and on real devices.

Here is my basic screen code that is overlapping the status bar.

Any help or guidance at all would be greatly appreciated. I've run out of ideas of what to try/test

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildLoginScreen(context);
  }

  Widget _buildLoginScreen(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Container(
          color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('top screen test'),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('bottom screen test'),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: resulting screen]

Comment: You app is not inside MaterialApp

Comment: wrap it with `Scaffold` widger

Comment: I have main.dart wrapping everything with MaterialApp, so it was inside it.
Wrapping with a scaffold had no effect

Answer (score 0):

FYI.
I had MediaQuery wrapping my main MaterialApp that is wrapping everything else. After removing this the SafeArea started working again. I have no idea why this happened now and not before, and I haven't yet seen if there are other consequences of removing the MediaQuery wrapper